# Covering Maps Abelian Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry

I am trying to understand a sentence I found in a paper christened "Tori and Jacobians" by M. Cornalba. The sentence is the following:
Let $X$ be a complex connected and compact Lie group. Consider its universal cover $p: \tilde{X} \rightarrow X.$ It is clear that $\tilde{X}$ is an abelian, simply connected Lie group. The article further says that $\tilde{X}$ is therefore isomorphic to a $\mathbb{C}^N$ and I do not understand why. Can someone give a proof or at least an argument of how that works? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathfrak x$ be the Lie algebra of $\tilde X$. Since $\tilde X$ is abelian, $\exp\colon\mathfrak{x}\longrightarrow\tilde X$ is a group homomorphism. Since $\tilde X$ is connected, and $\exp(\mathfrak{x})$ is a neighborhood of $e_{\tilde X}$, $\exp$ is surjective. Furthermore, its kernel is a discrete subgroup of $\mathfrak x$. So, $\exp$ is a covering map. Since $\tilde X$ is simply connected, $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Nice answer ! But why if $X$ is compact and complex then it is abelian ? (If $X$ is projective it's easy but I don't know how to do it when $X$ is compact).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet [All compact, complex, connected Lie groups are abelian](http://danielmckenzie.github.io/Compact_LG.pdf). I thought you knew this. Otherwise, I would have included it in my answer.

Comment: This is not my question, it was just by curiosity (and I knew that projective groups are abelian, but I was not sure that any compact Lie group was projective, I don't know much about Lie groups in fact.) Many thanks for this link !

Comment: Nicolas an answer to your question is the following: consider the function f_x(y)=[x,y] where x,y are elements of X and this latter is a connected compact Lie group. When x is the identity, f_x(y) is equal to the identity for every y. Therefore, when x is close to the identity f_x maps X into a coordinate patch. Vector valued holomorphic function on compact manifolds are constant, hence f_x(y) is equal to the identity for every y. Thus X is commutative.

Answer (score 0):

Half an idea:

Well...it has to be more than "abelian simply connected lie groups are all isomorphic to $\Bbb C^N$ for some $N$," because the 3-sphere is a counterexample to that claim.

What does "complex" in the description of $X$ indicate? That $X$ is a complex manifold with a smooth group structure? Perhaps that's a hint. Presumably, whatever it means, it lifts to universal covers. At that point some classification of simply connected even-dimensional Lie groups might be the answer...

Comment: Complex means that \tilde{X} is a complex manifold

Comment: I don't think this answer the question, especially because for example $S^3$ is not a complex manifold.

Comment: And that's why I started out with the header "Half an idea:"; I wanted to make it clear that the implied chain of reasoning could not be the whole story, and that something more had to enter into whatever hidden argument was being used.